# Star Trek TOS aliens won’t fight

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

Trying to recall the episode where at the end, Kirk et al confronted the aliens they were trying to defend. The aliens refused to fight for themselves for some philosophical reason.
Any ideas?

Comment: Re, "philosophical reason." Yeah, maybe, but the aliens also were absolutely invulnerable to their "attackers." Their humanoid "bodies" turned out in the end to be mere illusions that they created in order to communicate with we "lower-order" beings.

Comment: Per the accepted answer, you were probably thinking of the secretly-invulnerable Organians in the 'Errand of Mercy' episode. But, there are also some similarities to the peaceful/truly-defenseless Halkans in the original 'mirror universe' episode, 'Mirror, Mirror' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sounds like *[Errand of Mercy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Errand_of_Mercy_(episode))*, with Kirk trying to protect the steadfastly pacifistic [Organians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Organian) from a Klingon invasion force.

> **KIRK:** *Is that's all you can do, smile?*
>
> **AYELBORNE:** *You are free, Captain.*
>
> **KIRK:** *I want to know how I'm free, and why.*
>
> **SPOCK:** *Indeed, there are several questions I would like to ask as well.*
>
> **KIRK:** *This idiotic placidity of yours, your refusal to do anything to protect yourselves.*
>
> **AYELBORNE:** *We have already answered that question. To us, violence is unthinkable.*

Comment: I saw this episode a few weeks ago, and I'm coming the conclusion that Kirk is a self absorbed, condescending, ahole based on the way he treats the Organians and their beliefs.

Comment: @PeterM Did you not come to that based on how he treats everyone else?

Comment: @Studoku For some reason it finally clicked with that particular episode.  Yes he is self absorbed and an ahole, but what stood out for me was the condescending part.

Comment: @PeterM Kirk is emblamatic of the Federation, which was Roddenberry's idealistic vision of the continued progress of American exceptionalism. Almost all interactions with alien species demonstrated how we're morally more advanced, but this one flipped it around. OTOH, the aliens were only able to achieve their seeming pacifity through use of a superpower to protect themselves from aggressors.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps it was the flipping that highlighted Kirk's behaving like a spoiled toddler denied what he thinks is rightfully his.  But I can't think of another episode where the extent of that caricature was taken to such an extreme.

Comment: Out-of-universe: Whenever Kirk got to show his condescending a-hole side, that made it easier for Shatner to act the part. "Galaxy Quest" was inspired!

Comment: @PeterM A number of episodes got to show his condescending side when pointing out how much inferior the alien society is (e.g. "Taste of Armageddon", "The Omega Glory", "For the World is Hollow and I Have Touched the Sky", "The Cloud Minders"). But you may be right that this is his most "spoiled" demonstration, because he doesn't usually lose the argument.

Comment: Kirk has strong convictions about how the universe should be ordered. In classic Greek-drama fashion, this is both what makes him effective and what makes him vulnerable. Not only does it make for good theater, it's also fairly realistic (see e.g. Steve Jobs' perfectionism)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (though not being so important to the story line) is "Mirror, Mirror" where the Halkan's refuse to fight against the Terran Empire.

Comment: As the work has already been identified I feel this is more appropriate for a comment on the question. There’s a meta around here somewhere for answers like this saying they should really be comments but I can’t find it at the moment I’m afraid. For what it’s worth, I think this likely would have been a good answer had the episode already not been found!

Comment: The work has been identified, but this answer actually more closely matches this portion of the question, "aliens refused to fight for themselves for some philosophical reason."  The Organians did not need to fight; the Halkans were willing to allow themselves to be destroyed.  So I believe that this answer adds value.